# Firestore: enablePersistence() and then using redux with offline database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, create-react-app

So, essentially, I'm using Create-React-App and I want to allow users to add data to redux either offline or online. I also want to sync redux with Firestore.

In my main attempt, I initialize my firebase settings:

```
// ./firebase/firebase.js

var firestoreDatabase;

firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase.config);
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence().then(() => {
  firestoreDatabase = firebase.firestore();
});

export { firebase, firestoreDatabase };
```

Then, to make sure this has fired properly (this is definitely wrong, but I can't figure out the best place to catch the `enablePersistence()` return... ):

```
// src/index.js

import { firebase, firestoreDatabase } from "./firebase/firebase";

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  store.dispatch(setReduxData()).then(() => {
  if (firestoreDatabase) {
    ReactDOM.render(application, document.getElementById("root"));
  }
  });
});
```

ACTIONS FILE

```
import { firestoreDatabase } from "../firebase/firebase";

export const setReduxData = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const uid = getState().auth.uid;
    const data = { newData: '123' };

    return firestoreDatabase
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("data")
      .add(data)
      .then(ref => { 
        // so, this never gets fired
        dispatch(
          addData({
            id: ref.id,
            ...data
          })
        );
      })
```

So the `dispatch` never gets fired, however, when I refresh the application, the data I entered `{ newData: '123' }` is added to the store.

I think my entire way of handling this is wrong. I don't like exporting `firestoreDatabase` as undefined and then updating it when `enablePersistence()` returns...

I would like to just `enablePersistence()` once and then use the cache or the server depending on if the user is online or not... Redux should operate the same regardless...

Any thoughts and feedback are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured out how to load Firestore properly in my application:

In my firebase.js file:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import config from "../config";

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/
firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase.config);

const database = firebase.database();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { firebase, googleAuthProvider, auth, database };
```

Then, I added a firestore.js file:

```
import { firebase } from "./firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { notification } from "antd";

firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

const handleError = error => {
  if (error === "failed-precondition") {
    notification.open({
      message: "Error",
      description:
        "Multiple tabs open, offline data only works in one tab at a a time."
    });
  } else if (error === "unimplemented") {
    notification.open({
      message: "Error",
      description: "Cannot save offline on this browser."
    });
  }
};

export default firebase
  .firestore()
  .enablePersistence()
  .then(() => firebase.firestore())
  .catch(err => {
    handleError(err.code);
    return firebase.firestore();
  });
```

And then I call firestore in my actions file:

```
import firestore from "../firebase/firestore";

return firestore
  .then(db => {
    var newData = db
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("userData")
      .doc();
    newData.set(data);
    var id = newData.id;
    dispatch(addData({ id, ...data }));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // notification
  });
```

Essentially, I separated out my redux and Firestore, but ultimately they are connected through the Firestore id.